# Importing a JSON file into an Azure database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm writing a RESTful service which receives a JSON stream, splits it up and writes it into tables in my database.   A bloke at work has suggested splitting up the applications, a RESTful one to receive the JSON and store it into a row in a table, then a second one to take that newly created row, read the JSON, split it up and write it into the relevant tables.

He's suggested this because of the pricing model of Azure, that doing it all in one process doing data reception and process from "external" sources costs more than receiving and storing the incoming JSON quickly and then using a second "internal process" to split it up.    Is he correct or does he need a lie down and more coffee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your way seems less traffic on Azure SQL, and less costly.

However, if you are implementing microservices or splitting takes a long period of time, it could be a different story.

[image]

Comment: Saving, loading, then splitting and then resaving the data made no sense to me at all, surely the extra processing would have extra costs.

I've shown him your answer, he's not happy, but I am :) ta